# Import a module into a module, can't explain what i'm trying to do

Tags: python, import, module

So, the following is an example. Here's a module (called feedy.py) in let's say, the core directory:

```
import feedparser

feed = feedparser.parse("http://site.com/feed")
[...]
```

A bad example, but anyway: my problem is in the main script (parent dir), I have to do

```
import feedparser
```

as well as

```
from core import feedy
```

However, is there a way to eliminate the need to import feedparser, since it's already imported in feedy.py?

Hope you understand,
Fike.

Comment: Why do you need to remove the import statement?

Comment: Make my code a little smaller ;). Not that it'd make much difference, but anyway just wondering if there's a way.

Comment: If you're not directly using `feedparser` in your main script then you don't need to import it. Conversely if you need code from `feedparser` in your main script then you need to import it.

Comment: Oh!.. that's what happened before, I'll just test...

Comment: In general, `import` is there to make your code smaller, not longer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In principle, yes.  However, it's not usually a good idea.

When you `import` a module, you effectively declare a local variable which is a reference to that module. So in `feedy` you have an object called `feedparser`, which happens to be the module `feedparser`, although you could at any time reassign it to be any other Python object.

When you `import feedy`, you can refer to any of `feedy`'s exported variables as `feedy.name`.  So in this case, `feedy.feedparser` is the module `feedparser`.

However, if you change the way `feedy` is implemented, so that it doesn't import (or export) `feedparser`, this will break your main script.  In general you don't want to export everything you have defined, although it's fine for a quick hack.

Comment: Ah it's OK, did a small test with `feedparser` and it's all good, thanks anyway :)

Comment: @fike If you're happy with this answer, you should accept it or at least vote it up. :)

Comment: I need 15 rep to vote it up :P. But I accepted it :). Sorry, I'm a nub here :)